# PHP Mysql_fetch_array fails if fieldname is 0

Tags: php, mysql

using mysql_fetch_array() for a simple query-

```
SELECT id, name, roll FROM student
```

I get->

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => sam
    [name] => sam
    [2] => 5
    [roll] => 5
)
```

But, if I replace roll with 0->

```
SELECT id, name, 0 FROM student
```

It sends->

```
Array (
    [0] => 0
    [id] => 1
    [1] => sam
    [name] => sam
    [2] => 0
)
```

The 'id' is giving '0'. Whereas the query works well in mysql.

is it a bug of mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: So, if I put any number as field- it shouldn't work properly.

Comment: Why not to use mysql_fetch_row or use MYSQL_NUM option as a second parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug. The array value with key as `0` is being overwritten.

Since you've not specified any alias for the column with constant value `0` its column name will be `0`. And this column name when it becomes the key in the array will overwrite the array the already existing value with key `0`.

```
[0] => 1      // for id
[id] => 1 

[1] => sam    // for name
[name] => sam 

[0] => 0     // for 0 .. THIS WILL OVERWRITE.
```

Easiest way to fix this is to provide a column alias as:

```
SELECT id, name, 0 AS FOO FROM student
```

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) takes two arguments. You signal with the second one how you want to get your results.

`MYSQL_ASSOC` will give you an associative array with field names (or even `0` if you decide to use it as a field name). You will get:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => sam [roll] => 5 )
```

`MYSQL_NUM` will give the resulting rows indexed with numbers, in the order you asked for them. You will get:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => sam [2] => 5 )
```

`MYSQL_BOTH` is the default, it will populate your array both ways and can complicate things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change your query to:

```
SELECT id, name, 0 AS zero FROM student
```